# I need some help finding this font please. (Whatisfont and fontfinder can't locate)

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I came across this beautiful don't and despite a lot of searching and online font finders, I can't locate it. Please help. Thanks so much

[image]

Comment: What makes you think it is a font?

Comment: Probably in the hopes that it can be recreated although I am obviously not sure.

Comment: Well that is a reason to *want* it to be a font, not to think it *is* so :)

Comment: Well I'd still take suggestions of an actual font that may have a similar look :)

Comment: Take some time and look through script fonts on free sites like FontSquirrel or even Google Fonts. That's what folks here would do to find one to recommend to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is hand written script, not a font. The tattoo artist may have free handed it or made a pattern from free writing.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it to be a font so it can re-created